# ASP.NET 4 Deployment MSBUILD

Tags: msbuild, package, asp.net-4.0, web-deployment-project, msdeploy

I'm using VS2010 with the Web Deployment Projects to create a release package for my web application. In WDP I have created some build tasks to for example transform the web.config, create some directories and remove some files.

Now I've migrated the web application to ASP.NET 4 and I've been looking at this feature in VS2010 called Package/Publish. Is it possible to use this feature and add custom MSBUILD tasks, like with WDP?

I would like to get rid of the WDP plugin if the same is possible with a default VS2010 setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the package/publish features are a part of a process known as the *Web Publishing Pipeline*, which is captured inside of MSBuild targets & tasks. For Visual Studio 2010 Web Application Projects (WAP) the file Microsoft.WebApplication.targets & Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (*under %Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications*) are imported into the project file. If you want to customize the package/publish process you should be able to.

Here are some links to get you started. If you have specific questions post them and I can take a look.

- http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.aspx
- http://sedodream.com/2010/03/10/WebDeploymentToolIncludingOtherFiles.aspx
- http://sedodream.com/2010/03/11/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployCustomProviderTake1.aspx
- http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.asp
- http://www.vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/
- http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/default.aspx
- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120703022755/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/)

Comment: Thanks Sayed, your articles are very helpfull. In addition I found this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/02/09/how-to-extend-target-file-to-include-registry-settings-for-web-project-package.aspx

Comment: @johan, yeah should have added that link especially cuz I'm on that team! I've updated the entry.